# Python Cant Write Results To File

Tags: python, file

I wrote the code below. it works but it can't write results to the file. It's about testing collatz conjecture. pls help its important

```
with open("MyFile.txt", "w") as file1:
    def test(x):
        if x==1:
            print(x)
            file1.write(str(x))
            print("=================================================================================")
            file1.write("================================================================================= \n")
        elif x%2==0:
            print(x)
            file1.write(str(x))
            test(x/2)
        else:
            print(x)
            file1.write(str(x))
            test(3*x+1)
    for x in range (2**100,9**100):
        print ("testing for ",x)
        file1.write(str(x))
        test(x)
file1.close()
```

Comment: Do you let the script run to the end?

Comment: @matszwecja theoretically, if they cancel execution of the script mid-way, `with` clause should close and save the file anyway (but while script is running, the file will be empty)

Comment: The end? I think we'll all be dead before that happens. Look at the range!

Comment: You can flush the write buffer with `file1.flush()`.

Comment: @BlackAnubis7 I removed the file close and made the program run till the end but it didn't work

Comment: @GordonAitchJay i made it shorter

Comment: @YagizTankut I ran your program and it works fine, but the file is getting extremely big really fast

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me. Maybe you're looking in the wrong directory for the file. Set the current working directory with `os.chdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Running your program creates an extremely large file really fast (more or less 10MB/s on my machine). The first line of generated file looks like this:

```
126765060022822940149670320537612676506002282294014967032053766.338253001141147e+293.1691265005705735e+291.5845632502852868e+297.922816251426434e+283.961408125713217e+281.9807040628566084e+289.903520314283042e+274.951760157141521e+272.4758800785707605e+271.2379400392853803e+276.189700196426902e+263.094850098213451e+261.5474250491067253e+267.737125245533627e+253.8685626227668134e+251.9342813113834067e+259.671406556917033e+244.835703278458517e+242.4178516392292583e+241.2089258196146292e+246.044629098073146e+233.022314549036573e+231.5111572745182865e+237.555786372591432e+223.777893186295716e+221.888946593147858e+229.44473296573929e+214.722366482869645e+212.3611832414348226e+211.1805916207174113e+215.902958103587057e+202.9514790517935283e+201.4757395258967641e+207.378697629483821e+193.6893488147419103e+191.8446744073709552e+199.223372036854776e+184.611686018427388e+182.305843009213694e+181.152921504606847e+185.764607523034235e+172.8823037615171174e+171.4411518807585587e+177.205759403792794e+163.602879701896397e+161.8014398509481984e+169007199254740992.04503599627370496.02251799813685248.01125899906842624.0562949953421312.0281474976710656.0140737488355328.070368744177664.035184372088832.017592186044416.08796093022208.04398046511104.02199023255552.01099511627776.0549755813888.0274877906944.0137438953472.068719476736.034359738368.017179869184.08589934592.04294967296.02147483648.01073741824.0536870912.0268435456.0134217728.067108864.033554432.016777216.08388608.04194304.02097152.01048576.0524288.0262144.0131072.065536.032768.016384.08192.04096.02048.01024.0512.0256.0128.064.032.016.08.04.02.01.0=================================================================================
```

What you might want to do, is to put a new line after each number, so that the numbers don't mix (some are integers, some are floats in scientific notation):

```py
file1.write(str(x) + '\n')
# or
file1.write(f'{x}\n')
```

Now the file looks like this:

```
1267650600228229401496703205376
1267650600228229401496703205376
6.338253001141147e+29
3.1691265005705735e+29
1.5845632502852868e+29
7.922816251426434e+28
3.961408125713217e+28
1.9807040628566084e+28
9.903520314283042e+27
4.951760157141521e+27
...
```

#### File location

Please also remember that the file will be created in your current working directory (you can check it with [`os.getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)). If you want it to reside in a fixed place, use [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) (as suggested by [GordonAitchJay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3589122/gordonaitchjay) in the comments)